# Live-Build won't build an iso image

Tags: 16.04

I'm trying to build a basic ubuntu minimal iso using live-build, for some reason the process won't build the ISO image, please could someone tell me where I am going wrong, I've been researching since last week trying to build the ISO, thank you in advance to anyone who can help.

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo lb clean

sudo lb config \
 --mode ubuntu \
 --architecture amd64 \
 --distribution xenial \
 --archive-areas "main universe multiverse" \
 --parent-distribution xenial \
 --parent-archive-areas "main universe multiverse" \
 --apt-options "--yes" \
 --binary-images iso-hybrid

sudo lb build
```

Comment: Just to add, I've also tried adding quotation marks around iso-hybrid but this makes no difference to the end result, no iso is created